# How to add a framework to multiple targets within xcode4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have a project that I started in xcode 3.x

It is using 3 frameworks.

Now I need to add an additional framework. The way I found is to go to the "Build Phases" of the target and add the framework.

Unfortunately the project has 2 targets and will have 4 targets in the near future. 
Therefore I have to add the framework to all targets.

Not that I am lazy but as a result the framework is listed twice in the navigator tree on the left of xcode 4.

If that has no implications then I am ok with it. I just got the feeling that my way of adding the framework was not appropriate.

Is there a way to add a framework to the

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately not that I know of.

To avoid the duplicate framework listings in the navigator tree, after you add the framework to the first target via "Build Phases", you can drag the framework from the navigator tree into the build phases list of the rest of your targets.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. The problem was probably rather cosmetic anyway. But I was just not sure wether they were any implications having a framework included twice (or fourth).